# laravel relaciones intermedias no quiere relacionar

Tags: php, laravel

tengo dificultades con relacionar una tabla
que esta estructurada de la siguiente manera
tengo la relacion citas

```
class Citas extends Model
{
    public function sede()
    {
    return $this->belongsTo(Sede::class, 'sede_id');
    }
}

class Sede extends Model
{
 public function municipio()
    {
        
        return $this->hasOne(Municipio::class, 'mun_codigo');
    }
}
class Municipio extends Model
{

  protected $table = 'municipio';
  protected $primaryKey = 'mun_id';
  public $timestamps = false;
  protected $fillable = ['mun_id ', 'mun_codigo', 'mun_nombre'];

  
}
```

> ```
> return $cita->sede->municipio
> resultado municipio=null
> ```

como podria relacionar municipio ya que el primary no esta relacionado y tampoco mun_codigo que es el que tiene los datos de la sede[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No deberías tener hasMany en tu modelo Sede? Qué relación tienen esas dos tablas en tu modelo entidad relación

Comment: igual no me resuelve lo que estoy intentando y si lo  tenia como hasOne pero igualmente el sede->municipio me retorna null

Comment: Para empezar, te falta poner tu modelo Municipio

Comment: hay esta en la imagen cuales son las tablas pero ya lo coloco

Comment: @L.Flor mira hay esta el modelo de municipio

Comment: Puedes agregar tu consulta por favor?

Comment: Explica mejor por favor el resultado que planeas obtener

Comment: Viendo tus columnas creo que la solución es esta: `$this->hasOne(Municipio::class, 'mun_codigo', 'mun_codigo');` Automáticamente creo que busca la columna "municipio_id"

Comment: @BetaM el resultado siempre de la relacion es null aunque exista

Comment: si @memezhukulento a lo que voy es que nos muestres por favor la consulta y con eso podemos comprender mejor que resultado quieres y hacer las modificaciones necesarias

Comment: De hecho de cuerdo con lo que muestras tienes al menos 1 relación mal, por que `Sede` no debe ser `return $this->hasOne(Municipio::class, 'mun_codigo');` sino en todo caso `belongsTo`

Comment: funciono ya pude hacerlo con $this->hasOne(Municipio::class, 'mun_codigo', 'mun_codigo');

Comment: que genial pero considera revisar tus relaciones pues si tienen errores

Comment: ya medieron la tabla asi